# Debugging transpiled/webpacked Javascipt Stack Trace

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I have a toolchain doing server side rendering for a JS application. Client side rendering is working, but when doing serverside rendering I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'variables' of undefined
    at Object.81607 (main:145914:80)
    at __webpack_require__ (main:216155:42)
    at Object.14002 (main:127698:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (main:216155:42)
    at Object.52537 (main:127802:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (main:216155:42)
    at Object.36219 (main:127690:45)
    at __webpack_require__ (main:216155:42)
    at Module.8336 (main:151773:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (main:216155:42)
```

How do I go about finding where this error is coming from?

Does (main:145914:80) mean column `145914`, line `80` of `main.js`?

- I don't have a `main.js` file. I assume this is the name of the file that webpack/babel generated. I do have `main.b4b6555b.js` so I've been looking at that. Is this correct?

I've worked out how to turn off minification, so in `main.b4b6555b.js` I have non-minimised code which is useful. But line `80` is a comment - so I assume I have something wrong.

Comment: You probably figured it out already, but you may want to enable source maps. This should let you see the error from the perspective of your source code, rather than the compiled output that webpack produces.